# How to check in a portable way that a file path is potentially valid?

Tags: c++, boost-filesystem

I need to determine that a string entered by a user is OK to create a file with that name.  My application is built on Qt and runs on Windows and Mac OS.

I've found a check function in boost.filesystem, namely native(). The documentation says, 'Returns true for names considered valid by the operating system's native file systems.'  Sounds like what I need, but the function doesn't work properly and returns false always.  I've tried both back and forward slashes in the path, and tested the function with both existing and non-existing paths—all these tests failed on Windows.  Thanks to chris (see a comment below) who pointed that the function may be intentionally broken (I tend to agree with that).

So the question is: how to achieve what I need?

Comment: Could you give a sample input that fails?

Comment: Sure. D:\Work\cpptest —that directory exists on my machine but the native() call returns false for it. (Of course I have escaped the back slashes in my code :-) .)

Comment: Perhaps it's the fact that they're holdovers from version 1. The header in 1.53 says *"These functions are holdovers from version 1. It isn't clear they have much
 usefulness, or how to generalize them for later versions."*

Comment: Why do it at all? There are so many ways for a file creation to fail, and most of them cannot be checked in advance. A two-stage check would only confuse the users. The fact that the boost function is broken should also hint of something.

Comment: Because I want to warn the user if a path was obviously invalid.

Comment: Couldn't you use a try-catch block when you go to open the file, and catch the exception that's thrown if the string is wrong.?

Comment: I could but that's not what I want. I don't want to create a file before the actuall data processing begins.